# Selenium : Combo selection makes page scroll in firefox

Tags: selenium

```
Select dropDown = new Select(element);
dropDown.selectByIndex(2);
```

When making use of the above code to select an option from the combo, it works fine with chrome browser by making the appropriate selection in the combo. The same code also works fine with firefox by making the appropriate selection in the combo but it also scrolls the page which is not supposed to happen. 
This behavior occurs only in case of firefox and not in case of chrome.

Is this a known issue ? Has anyone come across such a behavior while selecting an option from combo in firefox.

Comment: Did U checked it different driver versions ???

Comment: Yes, indeed they behave the same.

Answer (score 0):

In firefox browser, by default, `WebDriver` will move to the position where the element is located and select the same. This is expected behavior of firefox and whereas in chrome it will select the item without moving to its position.

Hope this helps

Comment: Once the action is performed it scrolls the page completely out of the area where the element(combo) is located.